# Tuning Excel calculation engine which uses MS Excel interop

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com

I am currently building an Excel calculation engine. Its purpose is basically to wrap the calculation logic of an Excel workbook in order to use the logic from a C# library.

```
using (var s = new Spreadsheet())
{
    s.AutoCalculate = false;
    s.LoadFromFile("D:/workbook.xlsx");

    // Example: Set B36 to 1000.0
    s.SetValue(1000.0/i, "SheetName", 36, 2); 
    // Arbitrary cell values could be set here

    // Calculate result values
    s.Calculate();

    // Example: Read B52
    var result = s.GetValue("SheetName", 52, 2)); 
    // Arbitrary cell values could be read here
}
```

The library is meant to work for arbitrary workbooks and a flexible number of cell writes and reads. I cannot optimize anything specifically for a workbook or a known workbook layout. The worksheet might contain VBA macros and functions. I've tried a lot to avoid Interop, but have [not yet managed to find any solution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262202/calculate-an-excel-spreadsheet-containing-vba-from-net-without-using-interop?noredirect=1#comment532393_262202).

Here is my wrapper:

```
public class Spreadsheet : IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    private readonly Dictionary<string, Worksheet> _worksheets = new Dictionary<string, Worksheet>();

    private readonly Dictionary<CellInfo, Range> _cells = new Dictionary<CellInfo, Range>(); 

    private Application _excelApplication;

    private Workbooks _workbooks;

    private Workbook _workbook;

    private Windows _windows;

    private Window _windowItem;

    private bool _autoCalculate;

    public bool AutoCalculate
    {
        get { return _autoCalculate; }
        set
        {
            _autoCalculate = value;
            if (_excelApplication != null)
                _excelApplication.Calculation =
                    _autoCalculate ? XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic : XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;
        }
    }

    public Spreadsheet()
    {
        OpenExcelApplication();            
    }        

    private void OpenExcelApplication()
    {
        _excelApplication = new Application {Visible = false};
        _excelApplication.ScreenUpdating = false;
        _excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;
    }

    public void SetValue(double value, string sheetName, int cellRow, int cellColumn)
    {
        var cell = GetCell(sheetName, cellRow, cellColumn);
        cell.Value2 = value;
    }

    public double GetValue(string sheetName, int row, int column)
    {
        var cell = GetCell(sheetName, row, column);
        var valueString = cell.Value2.ToString();
        return double.Parse(valueString);
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        _excelApplication.Calculate();
    }

    public void LoadFromFile(string location)
    {
        if (_workbook != null)
        {
            try
            {
                _workbook.Close(false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {}
        }

        var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.Copy(location, tempFileName, true);
        _workbook = _excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(tempFileName);
        _workbook.EnableAutoRecover = false;
        _workbook.ForceFullCalculation = false;

        _excelApplication.Calculation =
                    _autoCalculate ?
                    XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic :
                    XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;
    }

    private Worksheet GetSheet(string name)
    {
        if (_worksheets.ContainsKey(name)) return _worksheets[name];
        var sheet = _workbook.Sheets[name];
        _worksheets.Add(name, sheet);
        return sheet;
    }

    private Range GetCell(string sheetName, int row, int column)
    {
        var cellInfo = new CellInfo();
        cellInfo.SheetName = sheetName;
        cellInfo.Row = row;
        cellInfo.Column = column;
        if (_cells.ContainsKey(cellInfo)) return _cells[cellInfo];

        var sheet = GetSheet(sheetName);
        var cell = (Range)sheet.Cells[row, column];
        _cells.Add(cellInfo, cell);
        return cell;
    }

    public static bool TryKillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(int hWnd)
    {
        uint processId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr) hWnd, out processId);
        if (processId == 0) return false;
        try
        {
            Process.GetProcessById((int) processId).Kill();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Win32Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void KillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(int hWnd)
    {
        uint processId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr) hWnd, out processId);
        if (processId == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("Process has not been found by the given main window handle.", "hWnd");
        Process.GetProcessById((int) processId).Kill();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            var hWnd = _excelApplication.Application.Hwnd;
            TryKillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(hWnd);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

    }
}

public struct CellInfo
{
    public string SheetName;
    public int Row;
    public int Column;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        return obj is CellInfo && Equals((CellInfo) obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(CellInfo other)
    {
        return string.Equals(SheetName, other.SheetName) && Row == other.Row && Column == other.Column;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = (SheetName != null ? SheetName.GetHashCode() : 0);
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Row;
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Column;
            return hashCode;
        }
    }


}
```

Please don't kill me for my way of resource disposal, I will get that straight before using it in production.

As you can see, I have implemented caching of worksheets and single cells to speed things up a little.

I have disabled the obvious performance killers, such as screen updates. What else could I do to improve the performance of this Excel calculation engine? I have thought about not recalculating the complete workbook but only the read cells in a recursive way, but haven't found a way to do so, as `Range.Calculate` does not seem to calculate the cells which are referenced by the cells within the range, so that the values are not consistent with the input values.

Answer (score 6):

One thing that I saw that didn't look good was, your resource disposal here

> ```
> public void Dispose()
> {
>     try
>     {
>         var hWnd = _excelApplication.Application.Hwnd;
>         TryKillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(hWnd);
>     }
>     catch (Exception)
>     {
>     }
>
> }
> ```

I don't think that you should use a Try-Catch here.

If you hit an exception while trying to close the application it probably means that some other resource is probably in use, you probably want the user to know that something is still being used. letting the exception bubble up is probably one of the best things that you can do here, aside form a popup that gives you the stack trace.

---

you should probably make good use of the Disposable Pattern of the Interface as well.

looking at the [MSDN for IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)

When they implement the disposable pattern they don't use a try-catch in Snippet # 3

> ```
>  class BaseClass : IDisposable
>  {
>      // Flag: Has Dispose already been called? 
>      bool disposed = false;
>      // Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
>      SafeHandle handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);
>
>      // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers. 
>      public void Dispose()
>      { 
>          Dispose(true);
>          GC.SuppressFinalize(this);           
>      }
>
>      // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern. 
>      protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
>      {
>          if (disposed)
>              return; 
>
>          if (disposing) {
>              handle.Dispose();
>              // Free any other managed objects here. 
>              //
>          }
>
>          // Free any unmanaged objects here. 
>          //
>          disposed = true;
>      }
>  }
> ```

if you don't make sure that you are disposing the application correctly you will end up with Memory leaks.

---

it looks like you have created 2 Methods that do relatively the same thing

> ```
> public static bool TryKillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(int hWnd)
> {
>     uint processId;
>     GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr) hWnd, out processId);
>     if (processId == 0) return false;
>     try
>     {
>         Process.GetProcessById((int) processId).Kill();
>     }
>     catch (ArgumentException)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     catch (Win32Exception)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     catch (NotSupportedException)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     catch (InvalidOperationException)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     return true;
> }
>
> public static void KillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(int hWnd)
> {
>     uint processId;
>     GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr) hWnd, out processId);
>     if (processId == 0)
>         throw new ArgumentException("Process has not been found by the given main window handle.", "hWnd");
>     Process.GetProcessById((int) processId).Kill();
> }
> ```

one returns a boolean and the other does not. you should be using the one that does not return anything in your Dispose Method. the way you are calling the current method doesn't make use of the Boolean that is returned.

Answer (score 6):

At a quick glance, this

> ```
> public static bool TryKillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(int hWnd)
> {
>     uint processId;
>     GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr) hWnd, out processId);
>     if (processId == 0) return false;
>     try
>     {
>         Process.GetProcessById((int) processId).Kill();
>     }
>     catch (ArgumentException)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     catch (Win32Exception)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     catch (NotSupportedException)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     catch (InvalidOperationException)
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
>     return true;
> }
> ```

could be dry like so

```
public static bool TryKillProcessByMainWindowHwnd(int hWnd)
{
    uint processId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr) hWnd, out processId);
    if (processId == 0) { return false; }
    try
    {
        Process.GetProcessById((int) processId).Kill();
        return true;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    { }
    catch (Win32Exception)
    { }
    catch (NotSupportedException)
    { }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    { }

    return false;
}
```

But based on the [comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69301/tuning-excel-calculation-engine-which-uses-ms-excel-interop/93870#comment170831_93870) from [Lyle's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/18427/lyles-mug) you never use the return value, so you could just change the method return type to `void`.

---

Instead of using the `Dictionary.ContainsKey()` method you should better use [`TryGetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like

```
private Worksheet GetSheet(string name)
{
    Worksheet sheet = null;
    if (_worksheets.TryGetValue(name, out sheet))
    {
        return sheet;
    }

    sheet = _workbook.Sheets[name];
    _worksheets.Add(name, sheet);
    return sheet;
}
```

see also [what-is-more-efficient-dictionary-trygetvalue-or-containskeyitem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382740/2655508)

The same is true for the `GetCell()` method.

Comment: I was about to mention that when this Method is called it **does not** make use of the boolean return value, there really isn't a need to return a bool from the method, as it is coded currently

Comment: @Lyle'sMug integrated into my answer with credit for you ;-)

Comment: It looks like there is already a void method, but it is never used.

Comment: Yes, but it is throwing for the swallowed (in mine review) exceptions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. As I said ("Please don't kill me for my way of resource disposal, I will get that straight before using it in production.") I wasn't really seeking optimizations for the disposal but for the excel interop part. What you say about dictionary is a good hint for the general usage of dictionaries but not really relevant in this case where I have a handful of entries in the dictionary but interop operations which take >100ms. Thank you anyways!!